# `python manage.py qcluster` doesn't work on Windows 10, but the same project works on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, asynchronous, django-q

The problem is that I fetched a new part of the project related to `qcluster` from my colleague. I merged it with my project, but when I tried to use it with `PS C:\Users\b2b\Desktop\tech\squirll> python manage.py qcluster`  I received this error:

```
PS C:\Users\b2b\Desktop\tech\squirll> python manage.py qcluster 
19:32:12 [Q] INFO Q Cluster pip-september-tennessee-papa starting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\b2b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\b2b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main     
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Users\b2b\.virtualenvs\squalue-9_-wEM9I\lib\site-packages\django_q\cluster.py", line 12, in <module>    
    from django_q.monitor import monitor
  File "C:\Users\b2b\.virtualenvs\squalue-9_-wEM9I\lib\site-packages\django_q\monitor.py", line 7, in <module>     
    import django_q.tasks
  File "C:\Users\b2b\.virtualenvs\squalue-9_-wEM9I\lib\site-packages\django_q\tasks.py", line 14, in <module>      
    from django_q.models import Schedule, Task
  File "C:\Users\b2b\.virtualenvs\squalue-9_-wEM9I\lib\site-packages\django_q\models.py", line 28, in <module>     
    class Task(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\b2b\.virtualenvs\squalue-9_-wEM9I\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 129, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\b2b\.virtualenvs\squalue-9_-wEM9I\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\b2b\.virtualenvs\squalue-9_-wEM9I\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

What's odd, when my coleague used the same project that I have, via Github, on his Linux, it worked.

So, something is not set correctly on my Win 10.

I have the same libraries as he:

```
PS C:\Users\b2b\Desktop\tech\squirll> pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
PowerShell 7.3.6
PS C:\Users\b2b\Desktop\tech\squirll> pipenv graph
boto3==1.28.40
├── botocore [required: >=1.31.40,<1.32.0, installed: 1.31.40]        
│   ├── jmespath [required: >=0.7.1,<2.0.0, installed: 1.0.1]
│   ├── python-dateutil [required: >=2.1,<3.0.0, installed: 2.8.2]    
│   │   └── six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
│   └── urllib3 [required: >=1.25.4,<1.27, installed: 1.26.16]        
├── jmespath [required: >=0.7.1,<2.0.0, installed: 1.0.1]
└── s3transfer [required: >=0.6.0,<0.7.0, installed: 0.6.2]
    └── botocore [required: >=1.12.36,<2.0a.0, installed: 1.31.40]    
        ├── jmespath [required: >=0.7.1,<2.0.0, installed: 1.0.1]     
        ├── python-dateutil [required: >=2.1,<3.0.0, installed: 2.8.2]
        │   └── six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
        └── urllib3 [required: >=1.25.4,<1.27, installed: 1.26.16]
django-debug-toolbar==4.2.0
├── django [required: >=3.2.4, installed: 4.2.5]
│   ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
│   │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
│   ├── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
│   └── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
└── sqlparse [required: >=0.2, installed: 0.4.4]
django-environ==0.11.2
django-filter==23.2
└── Django [required: >=3.2, installed: 4.2.5]
    ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
    │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
    ├── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
    └── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
django-import-export==3.2.0
├── diff-match-patch [required: Any, installed: 20230430]
├── Django [required: >=3.2, installed: 4.2.5]
│   ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
│   │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
│   ├── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
│   └── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
└── tablib [required: >=3.4.0, installed: 3.5.0]
django-q==1.3.9
├── arrow [required: >=1.1.0,<2.0.0, installed: 1.2.3]
│   └── python-dateutil [required: >=2.7.0, installed: 2.8.2]
│       └── six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
├── blessed [required: >=1.17.6,<2.0.0, installed: 1.20.0]
│   ├── jinxed [required: >=1.1.0, installed: 1.2.0]
│   │   └── ansicon [required: Any, installed: 1.89.0]
│   ├── six [required: >=1.9.0, installed: 1.16.0]
│   └── wcwidth [required: >=0.1.4, installed: 0.2.6]
├── django [required: >=2.2, installed: 4.2.5]
│   ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
│   │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
│   ├── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
│   └── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
├── django-picklefield [required: >=3.0.1,<4.0.0, installed: 3.1]
│   └── Django [required: >=3.2, installed: 4.2.5]
│       ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
│       │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
│       ├── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
│       └── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
└── redis [required: >=3.5.3,<4.0.0, installed: 3.5.3]
django-q-sentry==0.1.6
└── sentry-sdk [required: >=1.5.5, installed: 1.30.0]
    ├── certifi [required: Any, installed: 2023.7.22]
    └── urllib3 [required: >=1.26.11, installed: 1.26.16]
django-q2==1.5.5
├── django [required: >=3.2, installed: 4.2.5]
│   ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
│   │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
│   ├── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
│   └── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
└── django-picklefield [required: >=3.1,<4.0, installed: 3.1]
    └── Django [required: >=3.2, installed: 4.2.5]
        ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
        │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
        ├── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
        └── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
django-settings-context-processor==0.2
django-storages==1.14
└── Django [required: >=3.2, installed: 4.2.5]
    ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
    │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
    ├── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
    └── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
djangorestframework-gis==1.0
└── djangorestframework [required: Any, installed: 3.14.0]
    ├── django [required: >=3.0, installed: 4.2.5]
    │   ├── asgiref [required: >=3.6.0,<4, installed: 3.7.2]
    │   │   └── typing-extensions [required: >=4, installed: 4.7.1]
    │   ├── sqlparse [required: >=0.3.1, installed: 0.4.4]
    │   └── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
    └── pytz [required: Any, installed: 2023.3.post1]
factory-boy==3.3.0
└── Faker [required: >=0.7.0, installed: 19.3.1]
    └── python-dateutil [required: >=2.4, installed: 2.8.2]
        └── six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
flake8-isort==6.0.0
├── flake8 [required: Any, installed: 6.1.0]
│   ├── mccabe [required: >=0.7.0,<0.8.0, installed: 0.7.0]
│   ├── pycodestyle [required: >=2.11.0,<2.12.0, installed: 2.11.0]
│   └── pyflakes [required: >=3.1.0,<3.2.0, installed: 3.1.0]
└── isort [required: >=5.0.0,<6, installed: 5.12.0]
fpdf2==2.7.4
├── defusedxml [required: Any, installed: 0.7.1]
├── fonttools [required: >=4.34.0, installed: 4.42.1]
└── Pillow [required: >=6.2.2,!=9.2.*, installed: 10.0.0]
freezegun==1.2.2
└── python-dateutil [required: >=2.7, installed: 2.8.2]
    └── six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
gunicorn==21.2.0
└── packaging [required: Any, installed: 23.1]
MarkupPy==1.14
odfpy==1.4.1
└── defusedxml [required: Any, installed: 0.7.1]
openpyxl==3.1.2
└── et-xmlfile [required: Any, installed: 1.1.0]
ordered-set==4.1.0
prettier==0.0.7
psycopg==3.1.10
├── typing-extensions [required: >=4.1, installed: 4.7.1]
└── tzdata [required: Any, installed: 2023.3]
pytest-django==4.5.2
└── pytest [required: >=5.4.0, installed: 7.4.1]
    ├── colorama [required: Any, installed: 0.4.6]
    ├── exceptiongroup [required: >=1.0.0rc8, installed: 1.1.3]
    ├── iniconfig [required: Any, installed: 2.0.0]
    ├── packaging [required: Any, installed: 23.1]
    ├── pluggy [required: >=0.12,<2.0, installed: 1.3.0]
    └── tomli [required: >=1.0.0, installed: 2.0.1]
pytest-lazy-fixture==0.6.3
└── pytest [required: >=3.2.5, installed: 7.4.1]
    ├── colorama [required: Any, installed: 0.4.6]
    ├── exceptiongroup [required: >=1.0.0rc8, installed: 1.1.3]
    ├── iniconfig [required: Any, installed: 2.0.0]
    ├── packaging [required: Any, installed: 23.1]
    ├── pluggy [required: >=0.12,<2.0, installed: 1.3.0]
    └── tomli [required: >=1.0.0, installed: 2.0.1]
pytest-responses==0.5.1
├── pytest [required: >=2.5, installed: 7.4.1]
│   ├── colorama [required: Any, installed: 0.4.6]
│   ├── exceptiongroup [required: >=1.0.0rc8, installed: 1.1.3]
│   ├── iniconfig [required: Any, installed: 2.0.0]
│   ├── packaging [required: Any, installed: 23.1]
│   ├── pluggy [required: >=0.12,<2.0, installed: 1.3.0]
│   └── tomli [required: >=1.0.0, installed: 2.0.1]
└── responses [required: Any, installed: 0.23.3]
    ├── pyyaml [required: Any, installed: 6.0.1]
    ├── requests [required: >=2.30.0,<3.0, installed: 2.31.0]
    │   ├── certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2023.7.22]
    │   ├── charset-normalizer [required: >=2,<4, installed: 3.2.0]
    │   ├── idna [required: >=2.5,<4, installed: 3.4]
    │   └── urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<3, installed: 1.26.16]
    ├── types-PyYAML [required: Any, installed: 6.0.12.11]
    └── urllib3 [required: >=1.25.10,<3.0, installed: 1.26.16]
python-docx==0.8.11
└── lxml [required: >=2.3.2, installed: 4.9.3]
whitenoise==6.5.0
xlrd==2.0.1
xlwt==1.3.0
```

Windows environment variables seem to be set correctly. I'm lacking of ideas what could be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the *versions* of the requirements are exactly the same? You can use `pip freeze` (or another package manager) to check the exact versions.

Comment: yes. In the beginning, the only difference was that he had the most updated Python version, but I did update it when we found that - nothing changed. I don't know much about the whole topic. I tried to recreate my psql db - nothing changed. I've reinstalled all libraries with pipenv - nothing changed. We have the same `.env`, `base.py`...

Comment: I was wondering if maybe there is some logic in the code that is only compatible with Linux. Another idea is that some additional library for Windows is needed, and the lack of it leads to this situation.